# Reading dates from file and updating table of database using Java

Tags: java, sql, date, file-io, plsql

I'm trying out some code. I want to read dates from a file in `DD-MMM-YYYY`, `DD-MMM-YYYY`, `DD-MMM-YYYY` format and update DB table using query

```
UPDATE CAL_TABLE 
   SET HOLIDAY_SIGN = 'N' 
 WHERE CALENDAR_DATE IN ('01-Jan-2013', '02-Jan-2013', '03-Jan-2013');
```

1. So, what should be the format of my input file from where I read dates. Currently I am having `txt` and `csv` files and I can read dates and save them into a string array.
2. Is it a good idea to put that `update` statement into a stored procedure and send array as an input parameter?

Which will perform faster `update` statement or the stored procedure? I am using JDBC connection.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestions are:

Do not put send your data to the db as text.  Use your java code to cast them to date objects and pass them to your database as query parameters.

Stored procedures generally perform faster than other queries because once you run them the first time, they stay compiled and the execution plan stays available.  Having said that, if you are always going to be sending a varying number of parameters, a stored procedure could get complicated.

Comment: thanks Dan, but i want to pass varying number of parameter all the times, that is why i was thinking about passing string array to db. i tried **String query = "UPDATE CAL_TABLE  SET HOLIDAY_SIGN = 'N' WHERE CALENDAR_DATE IN ("+strLine+");";** but it gave me exception java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there is a  IN Clause 1000 item limit.